# Connecting to RDS with MySQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm having trouble connecting from my local machine to my RDS instance with MySQL Workbench.  I get error 10006 each time.  When I go to create the connection I enter the RDS endpoint as host, port 3306, user, password but it fails.  My RDS instance is in a VPC and I'm thinking that is possibly the problem.

I am new to this so if someone could explain something that I need to change b/c my instance is in the VPC that would be helpful.

Comment: (a) Is your RDS instance in a private subnet? (b) is the "publicly accessible" flag true or false on your RDS instance?

Comment: ah..so publicly accessible flag is set to no.  I guess that needs to be changed?

Comment: If `Publicly Accessible` is set to false (no), then the DNS entry for your RDS instance will only resolve to an internal IP address (10.x.x.x, for example). So if you want to access it from outside your VPC, then yes, it must be publicly accessible.

Comment: that did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RDS instance must have the `Publicly Accessible` option set to `true` (or ON).

If the `Publicly Accessible` option is false (or OFF), then the DNS entry for your RDS instance will only resolve to it's internal IP address. 10.x.x.x, for example.

When the `Publicly Accessible` option is true (or ON), then the DNS entry will resolve to the internal IP address when queried from inside your VPC and it will resolve to an external IP address when queried externally to your VPC.